# Oracle - result based on one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
ITEM LOC ENABLED
100  A1   Y
100  A2   Y
100  A3   N
```

I want the result as:

```
ITEM     STATUS 
100     INACTIVE
```

If the ENABLED is marked N for any of the locations, it should return Status as INACTIVE
If all locations are marked as Y, it should return ACTIVE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
select item, case min(status) when 'Y' then 'ACTIVE' else 'INACTIVE' end
  from t
 group by item;
```